# Inconsistent behavior of ix selection with duplicate indices

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the pandas data frame

```
df = DataFrame({'somedata': [13,24,54]}, index=[1,1,2])

    somedata
1   13
1   24
2   54
```

Executing

```
df.ix[1, 'somedata']
```

will return an object

```
1    13
1    24
Name: somedata, dtype: int64
```

which has an index:

```
df.ix[1, 'somedata'].index
Int64Index([1, 1], dtype='int64')
```

However, executing

```
df.ix[2, 'somedata']
```

will return just the number 54, which has no index:

```
df.ix[2, 'somedata'].index
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-274-3c6e4b1e6441> in <module>()
----> 1 df.ix[2, 'somedata'].index

AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'index'
```

I do not understand this (seemingly?) inconsistent behavior. Is it on purpose? I would expect objects that are returned from the same operation to have the same structure. Further, I need to build my code around this issue, so my question is, how do I detect what kind of object is returned by an ix selection? Currently I am checking for the returned object's len. I wonder if there is a more elegant way, or if one can force the selection, instead of returning just the number 54, to return the similar form

```
2    54
Name: somedata, dtype: int64
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I could not find an answer to this anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass a list of indices instead of a single index, you can guarantee that you're going to get a Series back.  In other words, instead of

```
>>> df.loc[1, 'somedata']
1    13
1    24
Name: somedata, dtype: int64
>>> df.loc[2, 'somedata']
54
```

you could use

```
>>> df.loc[[1], 'somedata']
1    13
1    24
Name: somedata, dtype: int64
>>> df.loc[[2], 'somedata']
2    54
Name: somedata, dtype: int64
```

(Note that it's usually a better idea to use `loc` (or `iloc`) rather than `ix` because it's less magical, although that isn't what's causing your issue here.)

Comment: you might want to expand on the reason u get a series with the 1 and a scalar with the 2; iow because the index has duplicates